# How to find and replace string data in text file

Tags: windows, text-editing

I'd like to be able to parse a text file which contains data such as:

```
2014-08-06 18:06:15 e:\shared\filename1.Shared orphan entry BM-100
2014-08-06 18:46:15 e:\shared\filename222.Shared orphan entry BM-214
2014-08-06 18:53:15 e:\shared\filename92.Shared orphan entry BM-674
```

This is on Windows and I'd like to be able to run a batch file script to remove the date string and text following the .shared file extension.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You want the Unix utility **sed**, which handles regular expression edits and is available in numerous Windows versions (just look for **sed.exe**). If you pass the file name to your batch file, it should contain something like:

```
sed <"%1" 's/\.Shared .*$'//|sed 's/^.* .* //' >"%1.mod"
```

This deletes in each line from "**.Shared** " to the end of line, then from the start of line up to the second blank, and saves the result in the passed file name with **.mod** appended.

You can of course remove either or both redirections and instead redirect input and/or output when the batch file is invoked.

Comment: There are of course more elegant solutions, with a single call to **sed**, but I thought that the two calls made the actions a little clearer - http://www.grymoire.com/unix/sed.html will tell you all you need to know about **sed** if you want a better command.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows Vista or later, you could use PowerShell

```
(gc D:\input.txt) | % {$_ -replace "2014", "xxx"} | sc D:\input.txt
```

- `gc myPath` Alias for Get-Content to read in a file
- `|` pipe the text to next command
- `()` must be used or else the input file is still open when you want to write it back
- `% { ... }` Alias for ForEach-Object which iterates through every line
- `-replace LookFor, ReplaceWith` replaces your string
- `sc myPath` Alias for Set-Content to write the new content back to the same path

---

#### Further reading

- http://ss64.com/ps/

Comment: OutOfMemoryException will occur for large files. Tried with input file 1.75GB

Answer (score 0):

Using this python script (which comes built-in with most linux distros and is an easy [install](https://www.python.org/downloads/) for Windows):

```
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_file = sys.argv[1]
    output_file = sys.argv[2]

    with open(input_file) as fp:
        with open(output_file, 'w') as fp_w:
            for line in fp:
                fp_w.write("{}\n".format(line.split(' ')[2]))
```

You'll get this output:

```
e:\shared\filename1.Shared
e:\shared\filename222.Shared
e:\shared\filename92.Shared
```

---

Steps to creating the python script:

1. create a file named `parser.py` (or whatever you want to call it)
2. copy the code above into the file
3. run the following command:

   `python parser.py test.txt test_output.txt`

   This assumes that `test.txt` is the input file, and `test_output.txt` is the file path that you want to write the results to.

Answer (score 0):

#### Windows command prompt

```
for /f "tokens=2-3"   %i in (x.txt) do echo %i %j
```

results in

```
18:53:15 e:\shared\filename92.Shared
```

***(or)***

```
for /f "tokens=3"   %i in (x.txt) do echo %i
```

result in

```
e:\shared\filename92.Shared
```